# Resampling spectral data?

Tags: visible-light, measurements, wavelength

I want to use the CIE CMFs (Color Matching Functions) 
[image: CMFs]

provided here: http://www.cvrl.org/cmfs.htm

With data from my spectrometer in 10 nm increments.

However, the CMFs are only provided at 5 nm increments.

What would be the best way to do this?
Would it be okay to resample the spectral data with a linear interpolation?
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have any expertise on the topic, but looking at the graph you provided, it's certainly looks smooth enough to be up or down-sampled to either 5 nm or 10 nm increments without causing problems (since the major features are on the order of 100 nm wide). I guess it depends on what precision you're looking for, of course.

Comment: So downsampling the functions is better than "upsampling" the measurement? Thanks

Comment: Is the graph you provide the measurement or the CMF? If both of them are fairly smooth (compared to the 5 nm or 10 nm step size) then it probably won't make much difference whether you upsample the measurement or downsample the CMF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely fine to interpolate color matching functions since they are nice and smooth. I would use spline interpolation instead of linear, but with such small increments (5 nm) you will hardly see a difference.